# How actually is used card table structure during garbage-collector between multiple threads?

Tags: garbage-collection, jvm

I actually have two questions 1) I have studied various articles and answers here about garbage collection and I can't understand the answer to the question: how is "card table" structure used during garbage collector between multiple threads? I think I'm missing something to understand it. 2) Is it right that this structure "card table" is used only in concurrent garbage collectors?

Comment: Your question is unclear.  What are you actually asking by "how is "card table" structure used during garbage collector between multiple threads?".  What question in your head is not addressed by the articles that you read?  If you are not specific, we can't understand what you are asking.

Comment: The answer to 2) is Yes.   For 1) ... I don't see how the card table relates to multiple threads.   (Yes ... you are probably missing something.  But I have no idea what it is. I could only guess, given that I / we can't read your mind.   See above.)

Comment: @StephenC I mean isn't the old generation divided into spaces for flows? the table is construct for all threads at the same time or distinct table for each thread separately

Comment: I don't understand what you are saying.  Please make your changes to the Question using the [EDIT button](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/72022169/edit).  Make sure that you express yourself clearly and with sufficient detail to allow someone to understand what you are actually asking.

Answer (score 2):

Card Table is a primitive implementation of a Remembered Set based on a bitmap. One bit in a Card Table corresponds to one or more words in a heap generation (or region).

The purpose of a remembered set is to track references from old generation to young generation - in order to update references in old gen when doing a young-only collection. So a remembered set, or a Card Table as its particular implementation, is inherent to generational/regional collectors, no matter concurrent or not.

Card Table is not specific to concurrent collectors and it has nothing to do with multithreading. Even the Serial GC [uses](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/4919525ddb55ba52d199a37c3b0e14e4a0c7c738/src/hotspot/share/gc/serial/genMarkSweep.cpp#L117-L122) the Card Table. I found the [traces](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-4213056) of `gc/gen/cardtable.c` in JDK 1.2 sources dated 1999, when there were no concurrent garbage collectors at all.